# How to create file uploading web service using node js with jwt Authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, web-services

I want to create file uploading web service with jwt Authentication such that peoples can upload there files to /upload route and I will use cloudinary service in my server to actually store them. User can also get their files using filename with /getfile route. Is there something else I should add in my project?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the express server to be able to take a file as an input I would use the package [Express file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) in order to achieve this. The docs are super simple for this one.

Inside of your server.js file:

```js
// setting temp files location
app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
}));
```

upload route:

```js
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
res.download('/report-12345.pdf')
});
```

This file obeject caqn then be used to save the file wherever you desire.

For sending the file back to the user Express also has a feature for this which is documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

getfile route:

```js
app.get('/getfile', function(req, res) {
  // whatever file to be downloaded here
  res.download('/report-12345.pdf')
});
```

Hope that's what you were asking for. Thanks!

Comment: But the directory where files are uploaded to/downloaded from must be user-specific, because every user shall only see their own files. Use a package like https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/ to fill `req.user` and then determine the `tempFileDir` dynamically based on that.

Comment: I am storing files in cloudinary so i think i can't use res.download because cloudinary return url of file not file itself am i correct?